# $scope values in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a quick question regarding scope values and assignment in AngularJS. This will probably sound a bit silly, but I'm curious about it.

Assuming I am using `controllerAs` syntax, and my controller instance is `ctrl`, I have say, something, like a form with an input like this:

```
<form name="ctrl.form">
 <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.firstName" />
</form>
```

Why can I do this in my controller:

```
if(this.form.$valid) {
    //code...
}
```

But not this:

```
var form = this.form;

if(form.$valid) {
    //code
}
```

The first example works, but the second example returns `undefined`. Am I missing something simple here with variable assignment? Since `this.form` holds a value, why is it not assigned to `form`?

Thanks!

Comment: depends when you assign it...show full context. `this.form` won't be defined until view is compiled

Comment: Instead of editing your question, you should post your solution as an answer.

Comment: Right, just did that! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

I have solved the issue - the reason that the second example was returning undefined was because the variables were being assigned outside of the form submit function. IE in full context, here is my entire file before where I was getting undefined:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

//signup controller definition
var SignupCtrl = function($http, $q, User, FormTools) {

    var firstName = this.firstName,
        lastName  = this.lastName,
        password  = this.password,
        form      = this.signupForm;        


    function submitRegistration() {

        //check if the form is valid
        if(form.$valid) {
            console.log("valid");
            var user = {
                firstName: firstName,
                lastName:  lastName,
                password:  password
            };

            User.createUser(user)
            .then(function(response) {              
                console.log('user saved!');             
            }, function(err) {              
                console.error('error, user wasn\'t saved. reason: ' + err);             
            });
        //if the form isn't valid at all
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    this.submitRegistration = submitRegistration;


};


angular
    .module('signup', [])

    .config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('signup', {
                url: '/signup',
                //path relative to index.html
                templateUrl: 'modules/signup/signup.html',
                controllerAs: 'signup',
                controller: 'SignupCtrl'
            });
    }])

    .controller('SignupCtrl', [     
        '$http', 
        '$q', 
        'User', 
        'FormTools',        
        SignupCtrl
    ]);

})();
```

The submitRegistration function was being called on form submit in my form:

```
<form ng-submit="signup.submitRegistration()" id="signup-form" name="signup.signupForm" novalidate>
```

I am guessing that the variables with respect to the form (ie. `this.firstName`, `this.lastName`, etc.) were `undefined` until the submit function is called. To remedy this, I just swapped where I was assigning the variables:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

//signup controller definition
var SignupCtrl = function($http, $q, User, FormTools) {

    function submitRegistration() {

        var firstName = this.firstName,
            lastName  = this.lastName,
            password  = this.password,
            form      = this.signupForm;

        //check if the form is valid
        if(form.$valid) {
            console.log("valid");
            var user = {
                firstName: firstName,
                lastName:  lastName,
                password:  password
            };

            User.createUser(user)
            .then(function(response) {              
                console.log('user saved!');             
            }, function(err) {              
                console.error('error, user wasn\'t saved. reason: ' + err);             
            });
        //if the form isn't valid at all
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    this.cool = function() {
        console.dir(this.signupForm);
    };

    this.submitRegistration = submitRegistration;

    this.sayHello = User.sayHello;  

};


angular
    .module('signup', [])

    .config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('signup', {
                url: '/signup',
                //path relative to index.html
                templateUrl: 'modules/signup/signup.html',
                controllerAs: 'signup',
                controller: 'SignupCtrl'
            });
    }])

    .controller('SignupCtrl', [     
        '$http', 
        '$q', 
        'User', 
        'FormTools',        
        SignupCtrl
    ]);

})();
```

Now that the variables were moved into the local function scope, it works. I am guessing that the controller does not have access to those variables until the form is submitted, but I could be wrong on that.

PS: In case you are wondering why I define my controller function outside of `.controller()`, I find it's easier to debug because in case of exceptions, I will have a named function in my stack trace instead of an anonymous one.

Thanks!